# Java decompressing archive packed by implode method

Tags: java, zip, implode, compression

I need to create some software which works with ZIP archives compressed with very old implode method.

Tried to write decompressor but nothing good happened. Optimized C-code is very hard for me.
Found this C-implementation ([here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/zip/zip-6/unzip/unzip/explode.c)) but cannot write it on Java. Just found request in Apache-commons about this feature ([JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COMPRESS-115) contatin link to APPNOTES.TXT with method description).

I should write cross-platform decompressor for this method.
Perfect is native-Java implementation.
Looking for help. Thanks.

Comment: I found solution in sevenzipjbinding library.

Comment: In case anyone finds this helpful: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6432010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sevenzipjbinding](http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/) - 7-Zip-JBinding is a java wrapper for 7-Zip C++ library. It allows extraction of many archive formats using a very fast native library directly from java through JNI.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the version 1.7 Apache Commons Compress can decompress imploded and shrunk zip entries. This is a pure Java implementation of the algorithm.

http://commons.apache.org/compress/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try if [TrueZip](http://truezip.java.net/) supports those older formats?

Comment: Returns the default compression method for entries. This property is only used if a ZipEntry does not specify a compression method. Legal values are ZipEntry.STORED, ZipEntry.DEFLATED and ZipEntry.BZIP2. 

Implode method is unsupported.

Comment: Any ideas more? Bkz TrueZip dont support IMPLODED method.